# How to set favorite user search input? JS

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm working on my weather web application. When user type his city in search bar, the app show 5 days forecast. Need to set button to save the city in browser storage or cookie. When user refresh the web, automatic loading his favorite city.

This is my html:

```
<div id="search">
    <input type="text" id="serach-city-input">
    <a id="search-city-button" class="btn btn-danger">Search</a>
</div>
```

And JS for connecting with API:

```
$('#search-city-button').on('click', () => {
    const searchString = $('#serach-city-input').val();
    weatherPage.render(searchString);
    weatherPage.renderThreeHours(searchString);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? The code you provided gives context, but doesn't even attempt to do what you're asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#search-city-button').on('click', () => {
    const searchString = $('#serach-city-input').val();
    localStorage.setItem('serach-city-input', searchString);
    weatherPage.render(searchString);
    weatherPage.renderThreeHours(searchString);
});

function fillValueFromStorege() {
  const storagedValue = localStorage.getItem('serach-city-input');
  if (storagedValue) {
    $('#serach-city-input').val(storagedValue);
    $('#search-city-button').click()
  }
}

fillValueFromStorege()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search">
    <input type="text" id="serach-city-input">
    <a id="search-city-button" class="btn btn-danger">Search</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I create new button to add it to favorite but in this case https://pastebin.com/vHK6E8Ce i get Uncaught TypeError: localStorage.geItem is not a function  at fillValueFromStorege (app.js:26)  at app.js:33

Comment: @MartinHristov PARDON localStorage.getItem (not localStorage.geItem) - it was syntax error (missed t)

Comment: Thanks, I'm blind :) https://pastebin.com/XkMPwFes this time i have error: Uncaught ReferenceError: searchString is not defined. It's strange because on of test times it set one city for favorite, and when refresh, the page load it. But cant change it when search another city.

Comment: Fixed it, searchString was in scope of search function. Reused it in $('#favorite-button').on('click', () => { and it work correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `localStorage.setItem('favoriteCity', searchString)` to save the value of the user when clicking the button save. 
Then when you load the page use `localStorage.getItem('favoriteCity')` to retrieve the value saved. You should have a method Init() or something that use your `render(localStorage.getItem('favoriteCity'))`